# Vagrant error /sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null for Alpine Linux v3.13

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtual-machine, alpine-linux

I am facing a weird issue only when trying to boot Vagrant using `generic/alpine313`, if I change the box to `generic/alpine312` it works like a charm. I do need Alpine v3.13 instead of v3.12.

Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  
  # Define Vagrant Box to be imported
  config.vm.box = "generic/alpine313"

  # We based our env on VirtualBox
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox"

  # Disable the installation of the host's VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest system
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false

  # Run build script
  config.vm.provision 'shell' do |s|
    s.name = 'Starting configuration process'
    s.path = 'build.sh'
  end
  
  # Sync local to guest directory
  options = {
    type: 'nfs',
    rsync__args: ['--verbose', '--archive', '--delete', '-z', '--copy-links', '--chmod=ugo=rwX'],
    create: true,
    mount_options: [],
    nfs_udp: false
  }
  config.vm.synced_folder './', '/temp', options  

  # Create host-only network
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"

end
```

Error after `vagrant up`:

```
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown eth1 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution and extra information.

Issue reported to Vagrant project: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12247

PR with the fix: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/pull/12181 (**Not yet** available with Vagrant v2.2.14)

Manually patching the built-in Vagrant plugin for Alpine as per the thread below solves the problem until the new version is released with it: 
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12134